# Instagram API has retired comment deletion endpoint

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Starting from 2018/05/08 Instagram does not allow deleting comments for any posts.

We are aware of the public content changes that were affected immediately (https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/) but that is not causing this since our app was able to delete the comments until 2018/05/07.

We still can create new comments using the API, they are not affected (if the deprecation would have caused it).

This is the request we make:

```
DELETE https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/1/comments/2
```

=>

```
'code' => 400,
'error_type' => 'APINotAllowedError',
'error_message' => 'This endpoint has been retired',
```

This seems like a bug, since using the GraphAPI the comment deletions are still possible.

Was this a premature deprecation of the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

From 11-12-2018 Instagram close sandbox API and integrated with **Facebook**
  [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/)